# Does my mother require a Schengen visa to travel to Europe with me?

Tags: europe

My mother holds an Indian passport with a stamp for indefinite leave to remain. She has been in the UK since 1975 after marrying my father, who was a British citizen.

I want to take her with me to visit Europe. Would she need a Schengen visa?

Comment: She has ILR and lives in the UK since 1975 and still hasnt applied for citizenship?

Comment: It's not unheard of.  My wife was ILR for some 15 years before we saw the way the wind was blowing, and she naturalised a few years back.  And look at all those poor Windrush migrants, who thought for forty-odd years that when HMG had said that you had the right to live in the UK that you could take their word for it ever after, and that paperwork was unnecessary in the brave new world.

Comment: What is your citizenship? From your question I am guessing British but it's better to be sure.

Comment: Yes she didnt want a british passport so she didnt change it she just kept the stamp. I am british

Comment: If your mother is dependent on you, or if she is traveling with her British spouse, the visa should be free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK does not entitle a person to travel visa free to Schengen states. Although she has lived in UK for decades, as an Indian national she would have to apply for a visa (generally to the country of your main destination or where you will spend the most days).